# How to have a choose image button with a preview of last taken image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am building a camera app and would like to have the last taken photo show up as a button to choose a photo. How would I do that?

Right now I am using **UIImagePickerController** to choose the image, and **UIButton** with just text to bring up the controller.

```
@IBAction func choosePhotoBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String]
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want it to look like the stock camera app.

https://i1.wp.com/9to5mac.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2013/09/screen-shot-2013-09-20-at-9-56-50-am.png?resize=1600%2C1000&quality=82&strip=all

Comment: Please explain more what you want to say

Comment: @GouravJoshi I would like to know how to create a button that gets the last taken photo from a users camera roll and set that image to the button image. Just like the stock app on the iPhone.